# Analogue of the Mean value theorem for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire. Let $w_1,w_2$ be any two distinct complex numbers. Must there exist $c\in \overline{B_{|w_2-w_1|}(w_1)}$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(w_2)-f(w_1)}{w_2-w_1}$ ?

**Note:**

I have shown the folowing: Let $[w_1, w_2]$ be the line segment with endpoints $w_1,w_2$. Then there exists $c_1,c_2\in [w_1,w_2]$ such that:
$$Re(f'(c_1))+Im(f'(c_2))i=\frac{f(w_2)-f(w_1)}{w_2-w_1} ...(1)$$

I was wondering whether allowing $c_1,c_2$ to lie in $\overline{B_{|w_2-w_1|}(w_1)}$ (instead of just the line segment joining $w_1,w_2$) enables us to choose $c_1,c_2$ such that $(1)$ holds and $c_1=c_2$.

Thank you

Comment: No, $f(z) = e^z$, $w_2 = w_1 + 2\pi i$ is the classical counterexample. You have the estimate, $\lvert f(w_2) - f(w_1)\rvert \leqslant \lvert w_2-w_1\rvert \cdot \max \{ \lvert f'(z)\rvert : z \in [w_1,w_2]\}$, and the two point-form for real and imaginary part. That's it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand the part : "and the two point-form ..."

Comment: Your equation $(1)$ in the **Note:**.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahhhhh :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general such a $c$ does not exist. The classical counterexample is $f(z) = e^z$, with $w_2 = w_1 + 2\pi i$. Then

$$\frac{f(w_2) - f(w_1)}{w_2-w_1} = 0,$$

but $f'(c) \neq 0$ for all $c\in\mathbb{C}$.

What you have in terms of the mean value theorem for holomorphic functions is the estimate

$$\lvert f(w_2) - f(w_1)\rvert \leqslant \lvert w_2-w_1\rvert\cdot \max \left\lbrace \lvert f'(\zeta)\rvert : \zeta \in [w_1,w_2]\right\rbrace,$$

and your equation $(1)$ with generally different points for the real and imaginary part.