# A Schwarz lemma like exercise, inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

Let $D_r=\{z\in \mathbb{C} | |z|<r\}$ be the disc of radius $r$, for $r>0$. Let $f$ be an analytic function on $D_2$.

Then 
(i)Prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|f^{'}(z)|\leq C $ for all $z\in D_1$.

(ii)Prove that $|f(z)-f(w)|\leq C|z-w|$ for all $z,w\in D_1$.

My try: By Cauchy inequality, I have shown that $|f^{'}(z)|\leq C$ for all $z\in D_1$ where $C= \sup_{z\in D_2}|f(z)|$. But unable to show the second part.

Comment: The second part is basically a corollary of the first part and [MVT analogue for holomorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633974/analogue-of-the-mean-value-theorem-for-holomorphic-functions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is a $C > 0$ such that $\vert f(z)-f(w)\vert \leq C\vert z-w\vert$ for a holomorphic map into $B(0, R)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695730/there-is-a-c-0-such-that-vert-fz-fw-vert-leq-c-vert-z-w-vert-for-a-h)